# Distributed Elixir example doesn't work

Tags: elixir

I have a very simple Elixir code sample I want to run on different nodes.

The first node is on my laptop, the second one is a Raspberry Pi, accessed via SSH.

The code is simple:

```
# node1@my-computer
defmodule Hello do
    def world, do: IO.puts "hello world"
end

# node2@raspberrypi
iex> Node.spawn_link :"node1@my-computer", fn -> Hello.world end
```

I expected that `Node.spawn_link` would print `"hello world"` on the Raspberry Pi, but instead it shows an error saying `** (EXIT from #PID<0.66.0>) no connect`

On the same machine with two different `iex` instances this code works just fine.

I'm starting the IEx session on `node1` with `iex --sname node1 --cookie secret` and on `node2` with `iex --sname node2 --cookie secret`.

It's also worth noting that on my Raspberry Pi `iex` starts with this warning:

`warning: the VM is running with native name encoding of latin1 which may cause Elixir to malfunction as it expects utf8. Please ensure your locale is set to UTF-8 (which can be verified by running "locale" in your shell)
Interactive Elixir (1.0.5) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)`

Comment: If you are calling `node@raspberry` from your computer (or vice-versa), you need to make sure you have declared somewhere that the host raspberry points to the raspberry IP, otherwise the runtime does not know how to find the "raspberry". Maybe a simpler way for now is to use IPs: `Node.spawn_link :"node@192.168.0.2", ...`. Also use the other functions in Node to find more information about what is connected and what is not.

Comment: I altered `/etc/hosts` to point `raspberrypi` to the local IP of the raspberry (`192.168.1.103`). Elixir complained that `[error] ** System running to use fully qualified hostnames **
** Hostname raspberrypi is illegal **`

Ok, so I went and changed names to IP's: `Node.spawn_link :"node1@192.168.1.103", fn -> Hello.world end` and it told me that `** Can not start :erlang::apply,[#Function<20.54118792/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>, []] ([:link]) on :"node1@192.168.1.103" **`

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple here.

Comment: OK, I got it. It was the IP thing all the time, I just screwed things up. Thanks, José!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to put the `@` sign in the node-names to get them to be interpreted as separate networked machines

```
iex --name node@machinename1 --cookie mycookie
iex --name node@machinename2 --cookie mycookie
```

and then in the first iex shell connect the nodes:

```
Node.connect :"node@machinename2"
```

Note the colon syntax that make the node name into a elixir atom. The quotes are needed because of the `@` sign.
You might try machinenames with the raw ip addresses first before trying dns names, if you are having problems
Nb: I use `--name` rather than your `--sname`

Comment: `Node.connect :"node@machinename2"` returns a beautiful `false`. Tried with IP as well. 

I read somewhere that there is a file Erlang uses, that have a connection with cookies.

Comment: What changed between your comments?

Comment: I don't really remember, but I'm pretty sure the IP had something to do with it. Use the raw IP address (e.g., `192.168.4.160`) instead of fully qualified hostnames.

Comment: In [this video example](https://youtu.be/lxYFOM3UJzo?t=296), José uses two Macbooks running Elixir 1.6.4 with `iex --name bob --cookie "secret"` and `iex --name alice --cookie "secret"`. His iex prompts appear as `bob@bob.local` and `alice@alice.local`. When I try, my iex prompt appears as `bob@<computer-name>.Home`. Able to connect with `Node.connect :"alice@<computer-name>.Home"` but calling code on the other node doesn't work.